# cakephp validation rule for time

Tags: cakephp

I want to add validation rule for time along with notempty rule, my code is

```
 $this->validate['StartTime'] = array(
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'allowEmpty' => false,
                'message' => __('err_required', array(__('lbl_StartTime', true))), 
            ),
            'time' => array(
                'rule' => array('???', '???'),
                'allowEmpty' => false,
                'message' => __('err__invaliddate', array(__('lbl_StartTime', true))),
            ),
        );
```

Please reply soon if there is possible solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use [time](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#Validation%3a%3atime) rule or if You need to validate time with seconds write your own [custom rule](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#adding-your-own-validation-methods).